# Definition Of Pre-Image

Tags: functions

I got the following definition:

> Let $f:X\to Y$ and $B\subseteq Y,A\subseteq X$
>
> The image of $A,F(A)$ is defined as $f(A)=\{f(a):a \in A\}$
>
> The Pre-image of $B, f^{-1}(B)$ is defined as $f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in X:f(x)\in B\}$

In the pre-image is there a reason that we look at $x\in X$ and not $a\in A$?

Comment: The preimage consists of all elements that map to $B$ under $f$. If there's elements in $X \setminus A$, then we won't reach those if we only look at $a \in A$.

Comment: The function $f^{-1}$ does not necessarily map just to $A$.

Comment: @DuncanH Careful, $f^{-1}$ might not be a function!

Answer (score 3):

$A$ is irrelevant to the definition; we are defining the pre-image for *arbitrary* subsets of $Y$.

Answer (score 2):

$f^{-1}(B) \not\subset A $ in general .  $A \text { and } B$ are just arbitrary sets, and there's no reason to assume the preimage of $B$ is contained in  $A$.

Answer (score 0):

$f[A]$ answers the question: "what points in $Y$ do we reach with $f$ from $A$"?

$f^{-1}[B]$ answers the question "what points from $X$ map inside $B$"?

The $A$ is just meant as arbitrary subset of $X$.
The $B$ is just meant as an arbitrary subset of $Y$. They are not related.

Exercise in the definitions: $$f[f^{-1}[B]] \subseteq B$$ with equality for all $B$ iff $f$ is surjective (onto) and

$$A \subseteq f^{-1}[f[A]]$$

with equality for all $A$ iff $f$ is injective (one-to-one).